# How to get rid of Ruby 1.9.3 notice in Ubuntu after installing v2.3.3

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, ruby

I'm running the ubuntu bash shell in Windows 10. To install SASS on my system, I had to install ruby, so I followed the documentation on the ruby website which downloaded and installed Ruby v1.9.3

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33064386/2308992) and followed the mentioned answer to install Ruby v2.3.3

So, when I run

```
ruby -v
```

it gives me

```
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

for the version details details.

[image]

But Sass is still using Ruby 1.9.3 and every time I compile SASS it shows me the ruby upgrade message even though I have ruby v2.3.3:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of Ruby v1.9.3 so that my sass can recognize Ruby v2.3.3

---

Also, there is another problem that I'm seeing: when I'm running the SASS command with the `--watch` flag, it's breaking out of the watch mode. Not sure if this has to do with any kind of conflict between Ruby v1.9.3 & Ruby v2.3.3 that I've recently installed. Here is a `--trace` flag output of the error:

```
sass --watch assets/sass/style.scss:style.css --style compressed --trace
DEPRECATION WARNING:
Sass 3.5 will no longer support Ruby 1.9.3.
Please upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0 or greater as soon as possible.

>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/watcher.rb:85:in `initialize': Invalid argument - Failed to watch "/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/homeloan/wp-content/themes/besthomeloans/assets/sass/partials": the given event mask contains no legal events; or fd is not an inotify file descriptor. (Errno::EINVAL)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:190:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:190:in `watch'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:204:in `watch'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:198:in `block in watch'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:194:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:194:in `watch'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapters/linux.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_worker'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapters/linux.rb:67:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapters/linux.rb:67:in `block in initialize_worker'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapters/linux.rb:66:in `tap'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapters/linux.rb:66:in `initialize_worker'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:87:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapters/linux.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:228:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:228:in `works?'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:190:in `block in usable_and_works?'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:190:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:190:in `all?'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:190:in `usable_and_works?'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:57:in `block in select_and_initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:55:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:55:in `select_and_initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:291:in `initialize_adapter'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:283:in `setup'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:65:in `start!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:408:in `listen_to'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:341:in `watch'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin.rb:109:in `method_missing'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:360:in `watch_or_update'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:51:in `process_result'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:52:in `parse'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:19:in `parse!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/sass:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
```

Not sure if this has to do with Windows 10 bash shell, but I though I should ask you guys as you guys are real guru in this.

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Can anyone help guys?